# How can I serve different template for nginx error_page according to app env in Symfony 3.4 app?

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-location, custom-error-pages, nginx-config

I would like to serve 403 template on local dev environment when I got 403 error, but would like to render 404 template for the same error on uat/prod.

I tried

```
error_page 400 /error/400.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html;
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location ^~ /error/ {
     internal;
     if ($server_name != "localhost") {
         return 404 /error/404.html;
     }
     root /etc/nginx;
}
```

and

```
error_page 400 /error/400.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html;
if ($server_name != "localhost") {
   error_page 403 /error/404.html;
}
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location ^~ /error/ {
     internal;
     root /etc/nginx;
}
```

But neither works. I only started learning nginx recently, so might have done above totally wrong. Wondering if anyone has any good ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use a different value for `server_name` for each deployment?

Comment: set it as `server_name _;`, no specific server name is set in the config.

Comment: So if `$server_name` is the same in both environments, there's little point testing it with an `if` statement.

Comment: so what would you think be the best parameter to distingush dev and uat/prod please?

Comment: Either the `$http_host` or `$host` variable will be set to the server name used by the browser in the request.